# how to close tabs element ionic

Tags: typescript, tabs, ionic2

I'm writing an ionic app with authentication page after the user logs in a tabs element is loaded and it control the different functionality of the app(profile, home, contacts...) everything is working fine but when the user logout it must return to the authentication page, i can't find a way to close the tabs element i know that every tab in the tabs element has it's own navcontroller(not the one i used to load the tabs element) and while the logout is handled by the pages loaded by the tabs so i dont know what thing is to be used to close the tabs element. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

i resolve it by passing the NavController of authentication page to tabs then to each tab with login button then call setRoot(HomePage(page of authentication ))function of navcontroller.